# SED append on next n-th line, not append to next line

Tags: sed

How can I get sed to append sometext two line after it find a match?

For example:

```
text0
text1
text2
text3
```

after I match `text0`, I want to append `text4` after the next 2 line, that is:

```
text0
text1
text2
text4
text3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say:

```
sed -e '/text0/ { N; N; a text4' -e '}' filename
```

That is:

```
/text0/ {  # when finding a line that matches text0
  N        # fetch two more lines
  N
           # and only then append text4
  a text4
}
```

When using this as a one-liner, it is necessary to split it into two `-e` options so that the `a` command doesn't attempt to append a line `text4 }`.

Alternatively, you could use

```
sed '/text0/ { N; N; s/$/\ntext4/; }' filename
```

this avoids using the somewhat unwieldy `a` command but requires you to escape some metacharacters in the replacement text (such as `\` and `&`).

Comment: whats the `-e` for at the end ?

Comment: To terminate the `a` command, as it says in the text. A newline in the string would also work, and so would a bash string `$'/text0/ { N; N; a text4\n}'`. The `a` command is not terminated by the `}`, nor would it be by a `;`, so we have to use other ways to terminate it.

Comment: Sorry should have read on, just noticed it wasn't in the desciption code bit, my bad :)

Answer (score 1):

Perl solution:

```
perl -pe 'push @append, 3 + $. if /text0/;
          shift @append, print "text4\n" if $append[0] == $.;
         ' input.txt > output.txt
```

You might need some more tweaking if the string is to be appended after the end of the input.

Explanation:

- `$.` is the line number.
- when `/text0/` is matched, the line number where the append should happen is pushed into the array @append.
- when the current line number corresponds to the one at the beginning of the array, the line is printed and the first element of the array is discarded.

It also means it works for overlapping matches and appends.

Answer (score 1):

I would have used `awk` for this:

```
awk '/text0/ {f=NR} f && NR==f+2 {$0=$0RS"text4"}1' file
text0
text1
text2
text4
text3
```

When pattern is found, set `f` to current line number.
When `f` is true and two lines later `f && NR==f+2` add new text `$0=$0RS"text4"`.
`1` print the result